# How do I switch Wi-Fi networks on Android without disabling the previous network?

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi

I'm encountering this issue on my Samsung devices running KitKat. It doesn't seem to affect my Nexus devices running Lollipop.

I use this code to switch between Wi-Fi networks:

```
private void switchToNetwork(String ssid) {
  WifiConfiguration configuration = new WifiConfiguration();
  configuration.SSID = String.format(Locale.US, "\"%s\"", ssid);
  // ... other configuration changes such as password and cipher
  manager.disconnect();
  manager.enableNetwork(params[0].configuration.networkId, true);
  manager.reconnect();
}
```

However, I'm noticing that if I was previously connected to a Wi-Fi network before running this code, these Samsung devices change the state of that previous network to "Turned off." This happens because the second parameter in my call to enableNetwork, `disableOthers`, was set to true.

The "turned off" state means that the network will not automatically be switched-to if the other network turns off. For my purposes, I'm manually switching back to the network, but there are certain cases (e.g. an app crash) where it might be desirable for the network to be switched automatically.

[image: Turned Off]
[image: Not Disabled]

When I change `disableOthers` to false, however, it doesn't always change me to the SSID I asked for in switchToNetwork(). It'll often stay on the previous SSID.

So: How do I guarantee that I'm switching to a new network without disabling the previous network?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by caching the current Network ID.

You can store the currently connected network ID using `getConnectionInfo.getNetworkId` API and store it temporarily.

Now connect to your desired network and when you are done connect back to previous network using ID you stored before.

Comment: is there any way to disable the currently active wifi network and connect to new one

Comment: There is a {WifiManager#disableNetwork} API which takes in Network ID as parameter.  There are more APIs, have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html